# Rails mailer with user editable template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer, devise-invitable

I am building a cms in rails where I want the site admins to be able to customize the email templates. so the mailer views needs to be editable via web interface.  I am using Rails 3.2 with Devise for authentication.

Possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using [liquid templating](http://liquidmarkup.org/) to do this. works pretty well & more importantly, its safe

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this would be to allow users to create markdown emails.  You can use [redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) or a number of other [markdown parsing tools](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=markdown).  However, depending on what you want to do, you might need to sanitize user input manually.